# restore project from jar file

Tags: java, netbeans, jar

first i'd like to point out that im fairly new to netbeans and java, couldnt exactly find what i need on the web.
I downloaded a software's source files and was modifying it on netbeans. naturally when building the project, netbeans creates in (for example) documents/project_folder/dist/ a lib folder and the finished JAR file that i can use.
if i delete by mistake the source files, and would like to apply all the changes i previously made to fresh source files using the JAR and lib folder i still have, is it possible and how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all it is not possible to get a source again from jar file in lib folder. Jar file is executable file which will just contain class files. You can use java decompilers to get source again.

Comment: i dont know if i understand correctly. thing is i have the unedited raw source for my project and i dont need to "extract" the old source from the jar, just apply a sort of diff to the new source using the jar. cant this be done?

Comment: okay done. just for the record: using JD, i ended up with what i think is the same source folder as extracting the jar with winrar. or is it?

Comment: Extracting jar gives you all .class files, which are not your source files. Thing is you get it in same folder structure as you have created your source. After extracting using winrar if you look at the files inside folder they are .class files not .java files.

Answer (score 1):

NB do not has a version control nor auto save by default. You may have a look on [git](http://netbeans.org/kb/docs/ide/git.html) in NB7.

When you restore from Jar with decompiler there is a big chance to get the source back, even more if you know what your code is all about.

Answer (score 1):

You can get the source back by using some decompiler. There are many decompilers available like DJ Decomipler. My favourite is [Jd Java Decompiler](http://java.decompiler.free.fr/). Its very small in size and does its job pretty well

Answer (score 1):

I'm rather an Eclipse user but I guess both Eclipse and Netbeans are similar to a certain extent. Unless the jar has been created including the source, you won't have other choices that decompile the class files.

When needed, I usually go with JD-GUI which does a pretty good job decompiling jars.

Answer (score 1):

It is not possible to retrieve **exact** source code from a compiled byte code. But there is a possibility to recover your code to some extent

JD is a good Java decompiler.
http://java.decompiler.free.fr/?q=jdgui

I think JD is a super hero in cases that the original source code is lost.

Answer (score 0):

Keep your source code on any SCM. Use remote SCM not to loose your code. See: google code, github, launchpad etc.